# What is the connectionstring to connect with postgresql using ODBC driver?

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working with  a task to connect with PostgreSQL and retrieve data from that DB to my .net application,I am using the code like

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL };Server=localhost;Port=2012;Database=DataCenter;Uid=postgres;Pwd=post@123;");
```

but it is throwing an `ODBException`. Please suggest me a code.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 3):

You may try that:

> Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=IP
>   address;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

You can definitely find more information on this website: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ 
And in your case particularely on this page: http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgre-sql#p51

If it does not solve your problem it is that the problem doesn't come from the connection string but your configuration of PostgreSQL. You might want to check that you're able to connect to the server using "psql" (for example) **from your client computer**.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

*For Ex:*

```
 string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                           "localhost", "5432", "postgres", "metin", "ATALAY");
```